# Selling dividend securities in after-market hours: Who gets the dividend?

Tags: stocks, investing, dividends, after-hours-trading

Consider this scenario:

During normal market hours, you buy a security 1 day before the ex dividend date.
You sell this security in **after market** trading that same day.

Who gets the dividend, you or the after hours buyer?

Does it depend on the specific security?

Comment: @Chris thanks for the edit - I wasn't sure how best to word the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The post 4PM session is also called extended trading, it's an extension of that day. Ex dividend occurs when the date changes, not when the day session closes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you cite a source? Also, how do you determine when the day ends? Is that midnight? In which time zone?

Comment: The after hours session on the NYSE is 4-8PM. It happens to be East Coast US time zone "NY". In theory, were there to be exchanges in every time zone trading the same stock, there would have to be a coordinated agreement as to the moment the stock goes ex-dividend.

Comment: So, whoever owns the security at market open in pre-market extended hours on the ex div date will get the dividend? Do I understand this correctly? So one could buy 1 minute before the end of after hours, then sell 1 minute after pre-market open, and they receive the dividend?

Comment: Yes. But, for example, a $50 stock with a $1/qtr dividend will open on ex-div day at $49. Of course, this example exaggerates the reality of the smoothness of markets. Check out the close on day one and open for day 2 and you'll find that world events came into play to help determine the days open. So a dividend capture strategy isn't so simple.